# Moved WordPress to root directory and HTACCESS still loading subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out why my WordPress installation is still pulling up the subfolder when I moved it to the root directory. Here's the HTACCESS file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm a super n00b when it comes to HTACCESS so am not sure even what I'm supposed to change. /wp/ is the subfolder that I removed WP out of and into the roote directory.

Cheers!
Olga

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the .htaccess in order to route your WP files. I'm not sure if you're saying you're trying to move WP into it's own directory, or the other way around, but if you have a custom path, route it through the `wp-config.php` like this:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------*\
    Custom Paths
\*--------------------------------------------------------*/

if (!defined('WP_SITEURL')) {
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp');
}

if (!defined('WP_HOME')) {
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}

if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_DIR')) {
    define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/content');
}

if (!defined('WP_CONTENT_URL')) {
    define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/content');
}
```

These four definitions tell the WP that the files are in the `/wp` subdirectory and that my content directory is in `/content`.

Now, if you are trying to achieve the opposite effect, that is, *not* having WP in a subdirectory, then you shouldn't really have to do anything. In that case, I believe this line `RewriteBase /wp/` is what's skewing your paths. If I were you, in this case, I would just delete the `.htaccess` altogether and let WP regenerate it itself. Whenever you delete it, WP will automatically regenerate the file, so you should be good.